# WPF binding throws exception outside debugger

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-debugging

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTextCrashTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTextCrashTest">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Inlines>
            <Run Text="{Binding StringToBind}" />
        </TextBlock.Inlines>
    </TextBlock>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public ViewModel()
   {
      StringToBind = "To bind";
   }

   public string StringToBind { get; private set; }
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   // binding to this works:
   public string Works { get { return "To bind"; } }
}
```

If I run the above application in a debugger (F5 in Visual Studio), it runs fine and the text is shown on the view. No exceptions are thrown and no error messages are printed to the output window. On the other hand, if I run it outside of the debugger (Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio), I get a XamlParseException with an InnerException of type InvalidOperationException with the message:
"A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'StringToBind' of type 'WpfTextCrashTest.ViewModel'."

If instead of binding to the `ViewModel` property `StringToBind` I instead bind to `Works` then no errors occur.

Can anyone explain:

- Why this error occurs?
- How I would go about ensuring that the application crashes consistently in future, whether or not it is in a debugger?

**Edit:**
To clarify, I'm more interested what effect the debugger being attached has than on how to fix the xaml / view model. This sort of bug has the potential to creep in during development and stick around for a long time (potentially after a story is published onto master) if all testing is done by developers using local builds. And obviously at that point it becomes a lot more costly to diagnose and fix. So I'm looking for a solution where the application behaves the same whether or not it has a debugger attached, either with the app always crashing due to a two way binding, or never crashing because a one-way binding is correctly chosen by the framework.

Comment: The version of Visual Studios may be relevant. The debugger in VS 2010 seems crash for me using the Debugger.

Comment: This occurs in visual studio 2013 and 2015, haven't checked any other versions

Comment: I have seen this before and it is because of your `private setter`. The Binding engine will access the Property on your ViewModel using reflection but it will not check if it can access it. See your `Works` has only got a `getter` so it will work fine but `private setter` will trigger an error. This was documented bug [MSDN](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773682/wpf-property-with-private-setter-is-updated-by-a-twoway-binding) it has been fixed in .NET4.5+

Comment: @XAMlMAX That MSDN link has a setting that can be added to the app.config to make sure it always crashes, if you add it as an answer I'll accept it. Being built as debug/release has no effect btw.